# What does that mean: "my toes speak English "?

Tags: meaning

What does "my toes speak English" mean?
From [GLEE - Full Performance of ''Telephone'' from ''Audition''](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cmNvWufXs8E&t=22s) at 0:22:
A woman thought that one another don't speak English and the other woman replied "my toes speak English" or maybe I misheard it.

Comment: Unless you tell us the context where you read this sentence, it's impossible to say - apart from the literal meaning which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Google finds just a single instance of the cited text. I don't really think it needs "context" anyway, though. Obviously it's just hyperbole for *I'm an Anglophone through and through* (I'm *really* familiar with the English language). Which doesn't necessarily imply the speaker claims to know every last detail of English syntax and vocabulary - just that she's generally knowledgeable about and interested in it.

Comment: @Laurel: I think the question should be reopened, because although this *exact* string of words is a one-off, the speaker / writer herself is clearly demonstrating intimate knowledge of the language by coming up with it in the first place. Many *other* native Anglophones (and I'm sure she ***is*** one) will be familiar with similar superficially nonsensical assertions about [what their little finger knows or can do.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22little+finger+knows%22)

Comment: The context should be in the post itself, not elsewhere on the internet or even behind a link. @FumbleFingers

Comment: @FumbleFingers Without more context, we're only guessing what that phrase means. Even though I agree with your guess, it's still a guess because it could be literally true, or someone using their toes as ventriloquist dolls, or whatever, so this isn't a good enough question as it stands.

Comment: @Laurel: I think you're being unreasonable. I can't see the actual words within that writers Facebook page (scrolled away, or whatever). Plus many people (including myself) don't like going to FB for *any* reason. Whatever - I will raise the reopern request on meta if you don't unbend a bit.

Comment: @gotube: ditto to you. I've clearly made my point about ***my little finger***, and I've no doubt I could find similar usages for other "minor body parts"

Comment: @FumbleFingers  The script, from the TV show Glee, has every word in the quote except for "even my toes". Instead it says: «SUNSHINE: *Um*, ***I totally speak English***.  
RACHEL: *I even did a little research on you. You are a foreign exchange student named Sunshine Corazon because you are from the Philippines where it's sunny every day!*»

Comment: My money is that "Even my toes" is either someone's poor mistranslation, or a mistranscription generated by automatic subtitles.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Can I ask these mods to delete your comments on the grounds that you haven't provided a link for your claims? :) I think it's vanishingly unlikely that "Even my toes" is a mistranslation, and the idea that "automatic subtitling" could make such a change is inconceivable. I think the (cited) writer is almost certainly a native Anglophone showing very good command of her language anyway, but I'm unwilling to go back to FB again to confirm that.

Comment: [Re-open request posted on meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5914/re-open-request)

Comment: Hello sorry for not gave the context yes it is from Glee the "cover" of Téléphone of Lady Gaga and Beyonce

Comment: You misheard it. She says, "Uhm, I totally speak English."

Comment: @FumbleFingers - in the TV show, I am now sure that she is actually saying 'Um, I totally speak English', but some consonants and vowels are not said clearly, and it sounds like 'oh, my toes speak English'. See 0:22 in [this video](https://www.tiktok.com/@clips4uandme/video/7159964027437944091)

Comment: The 'transcript' for that video even repeats the 'toes speak English' error.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  thanks my English is bad even by watching it many times I don't manage to hear um I totally speak English 

Comment: Vivel, it is deliberately said that way because the character of Sunshine Corazon does not speak English clearly. She is not a native speaker.

Comment: If it gets reopened, the answer will have to be that "my toes speak English" is a mishearing of 'Um, I totally speak English'. I don't know if questions that turn out to be based on a mistaken hearing are on-topic.

Comment: Ah ok Michael thanks

Comment: Maybe this does not need saying, but there is a joke here (_Glee_ is a comedy) which is that Sunshine says 'I totally speak English', like someone who _totally does not speak English_.

Comment: Ah ok thanks once again Michael I didn't notice that point

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Mishearings/misquotes are off-topic here because they were never actually produced. They're equivalent to, "Is this random glob of words correct English?"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey : its also my feeling that it's ironic pidgin meaning *I also speak english* : "My too[s] speak English".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because it arose out of a mishearing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sunshine's accent and speech, in a the few clips I saw, she is mainly singing though, sound perfectly OK. She barely sounds foreign.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I initially followed your closevote, because everyone here seemed to agree it was a "transcription error". But then i actually listened to the clip, and realised it's obviously *not*. There is an element of "auditory punning" based on the similarity of sound between ***I totally*** and ***My toes***, but that's nowhere near enough to "explain" the usage. It ***only*** makes sense as a deliberately humorous "neologism / coinage" building on related *established* idiomatic English constructions.

Comment: @everyone While I haven't actually listened to the clip, it seems possible that the character said, "I *totes* speak English" and this is where the confusion between 'totally' and 'toes' comes in.  **Totes** is a very informal slang word for "totally."  As in, "That puppy dog is *totes adorbs*" (for "totally adorable")

Comment: This sense of "totes"=totally has made it into dictionaries e.g. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/totes)

Comment: @StuartF: Read my Answer, inclusive of a 2012 written instance of ***I totes knew he liked you!*** (and more background for that particular *kind* of "diminutive" slang) The auditory pun I'm arguing for wouldn't really work if she'd said ***totally*** - which everyone here was insisting on while forcing the first closure. Now it'll probably get closed *again*. <sigh>

Answer (score 3):

**Sometimes the likeliest answer is the most boring.**

Which of these statement makes greater sense? Which line uttered by the actress portraying Sunshine is most likely?

1. **My toes speak English**

or

2. **I totally speak English**

Admittedly at first hearing, I thought the protagonist did say sentence no.1 then I listened again, with proper speakers and even though the line is muffled, and syllables are dropped there is no earthly way that any Hollywood director or script writer would have approved of such a nonsensical line. Simply because Glee is not that kind of tongue-in-cheek indy-comedy. If this were a sketch by Month Python, it would be more believable because many sketches were surreal and plain silly. This scene is devoid of clever puns, witty retorts and biting commentary. The acting is pretty embarrassing too, but I digress, here are the lines reproduced from [Glee Wiki](https://glee.fandom.com/wiki/Rachel%27s_Quotations) .

> RACHEL: Oh hello! I couldn't help but notice you admiring me yesterday in the courtyard.
> SUNSHINE: Um, what?
> RACHEL: Oh you don't speak English. YOU-LIKE-ME-SING! YOU-LIKE-ME-SING-VERY-MUCH!
> SUNSHINE: Um, I totally speak English.
> RACHEL: I even did a little research on you. You are a foreign exchange student named Sunshine Corazon because you are from the Philippines where it's sunny every day!»

Answer (score 0):

Sunshine says "Um, I totally speak English." The second "t" of "totally" is slightly swallowed/a very very soft "d." The "ly" is very fast, but it is present if you listen carefully.

Sunshine's response isn't intended to be a funny line in itself, just to point out Rachel's over the top racism in assuming that Sunshine can't speak English and then shouting "You like me sing, you like very much," which is intended to be the funny part. The humor on Glee was primarily based on outrageous statements and actions by the characters.

Here are two separate transcription sites which have the correct line. Additionally, per Billy Kerr's comment, the official transcription on Disney+ also has "Um, I totally speak English."

https://subslikescript.com/series/Glee-1327801/season-2/episode-1-Audition

https://gleetranscripts.tumblr.com/post/13214567480/2x01-audition

Comment: I don't want to get bogged down in tit-for-tat, but on the basis of what ***I*** hear, I have to downvote this.

Comment: There's a lot of missing syllables for that to be "totally" - It's probably "Um I [totes](https://slang.net/meaning/totes) speak English" which is a slang abbreviation for totally.

Comment: @ColleenV: I made that specific point in my answer, together with evidence to show that ***totes*** for ***totally*** is a known thing. But not that I had to figure that out for myself, wading against a torrent of comments claiming that s/he says ***totally***, which is obviously *not* the case.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This question is a stellar example of why audio transcription is out of scope for ELL. There is no "my toes speak English" anywhere in that clip and obviously the third party transcriptions aren't infallible representations of what was said syllable-for-syllable even if they do match the intended meaning. I question the usefulness of any of this discussion for a wider audience of learners. No learner should study the ridiculous American pop tween girl mangled pronunciation of anything.

Comment: @ColleenV: I think you and everyone else is missing my point here. It's irrelevant whether any given person hears, or any given transcript *writes* one version or the other. The words are *chosen* to enable the auditory pun. Which takes a little bit of work from both scriptwriter and actress to make sure that there's an ***Um...*** or ***Er...*** to blur ***I / My***, the second /t/ of ***totes*** is underarticulated to blur that part, and the pluralising /s/ of ***toes*** is deliberately slurred into ***speak***. I think it's very clever, even if it goes over the heads of many people here!

Comment: ...and I think it ***is*** on topic, for the specific reason that the pun depends on recognizing that utterances like  ***My little toe knows more English than you!*** are already out there in print (the ***toes*** reading might be "quirky", but it's not completely meaningless, or without precedent.)

Comment: ...whatever - I see there are now 4 closevotes waiting to trash the Q. I'm obviously flogging a dead horse here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are really reading more into it than is there. The mangled sentence is very typical of American girl pop singer affectation that some people think is cute. Glee is not that deep a show.

Comment: @ColleenV: I'm a postmodernist, so to me it's largely irrelevant what the *writer* of some text might have meant, or why he might choose certain phrasings. It's what ***I*** get out the the text that counts. And I get a very clever pun here, even if no-one else does. But I'd be fascinated to hear from the scriptwriters. Also let's not forget that the *original* source (now lost) was a Facebook user who specifically transcribed it as ***My toes speak English*** (don't remember if s/he included that crucial ***Er...*** before it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers There's an interesting article on the "indie voice" dialect: https://www.acelinguist.com/2021/05/dialect-dissection-indie-voicecursive.html I don't trust any transcription by default after poking around https://www.kissthisguy.com/  I'm an engineer, so not inclined to make up my own truth :)

Comment: @ColleenV: Well, so far as I'm aware, "kiss this guy" really was nothing but an "eggcorn" mishearing (Hendrix intended nothing like that). But to my mind, *this* example is deliberate, so it's more like [Carry On Cleo - ***Infamy, infamy, they've all got it in for me**!*](https://youtu.be/oBtOpA7x3LM?t=57) (But a bit subtler! :)

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. I just checked the subtitles on Disney+.  It says "Um, I totally understand English".  This isn't a third party transcription, but the subtitles published by Disney themselves.

Comment: @BillyKerr The transcript might accurately represent the script, but it doesn't match what she said in the video clip. Slow it down. There is no way she says totally. It's one syllable. She says "totes".

Comment: @ColleenV - nope. I disagree. She definitely doesn't say that.

Comment: @BillyKerr Which is exactly why questions about audio transcription are out of scope, and this question should be closed.

Answer (score -3):

I never accepted that "lack of context" was an acceptable closevote reason for this question, but now we *have* got [the full context](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cmNvWufXs8E&pp=ygUOdGVsZXBob25lIGdsZWU%3D) (0.22), it's potentially even *more* confusing.

So far as I'm concerned, the woman in that clip very precisely enunciates ***My toes** speak English*, and that's what the OP here is asking about, so it's nothing to do with "mis-hearing". The question to be asked is *why* would she say that, given it's not an established idiom (so superficially it looks like *nonsense*)?

The context is a *comedy*, and from what I could make out, the woman who says the line seems to be intelligent, articulate, and clear-spoken. She's responding to *another* clear-spoken native Anglophone who (for the purposes of humour) appears to be *unintelligent* (and thinks the first woman knows little English).

I think there's no doubt that ***My toes** speak English* is intended to allude<sup>1</sup> to ***I totally** speak English*, but imho that wouldn't be enough to justify the scriptwriters including the line. To me, it's a typically Anglophone "whimsical coinage" building on established idioms like...

> [***My little toe knows more English than you**!*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22my%20little%20toe%20knows%20more%20English%22&tbm=bks&ei=G5muZMGfM9O7gAacjo_wBw&ved=0ahUKEwiBmYS-komAAxXTHcAKHRzHA34Q4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22my%20little%20toe%20knows%20more%20English%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAM6BAghEApQhg5Y2TBg-TVoAXAAeACAAY0BiAHFBpIBAzcuM5gBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books) (your English is terrible)
> [***My little finger***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22My%20little%20finger%20knows%20better%22&tbm=bks&ei=0Q6uZJqCBZGZgQbv0pKQDg&ved=0ahUKEwjartfMjoiAAxWRTMAKHW-pBOIQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22My%20little%20finger%20knows%20better%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQjw9Y7BxgzShoAHAAeACAAVeIAfYDkgEBOJgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books) *knows more than your head* (*you're **really** dumb*)
> *I'm English* [***from head to toe***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22english%20from%20head%20to%20toe%22&biw=1536&bih=747&tbm=bks&ei=0KutZMXKIsSHhbIP9YisyA8&ved=0ahUKEwjF8ryXsIeAAxXEQ0EAHXUEC_kQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%22english%20from%20head%20to%20toe%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAMyBQgAEKIEOgQIIRAKUKINWINWYNBeaABwAHgAgAGMAYgBpB2SAQQ0OS4zmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books) (I'm ***totally*** English, through and through)

---

<sup>1</sup> It's only an *allusion*, and the line would still be funny if you didn't notice the ambiguity (*whichever* version you think you heard). I don't really understand how anyone could seriously think they *hear* the woman saying ***I totally***, given how clearly she speaks - and that ***toes*** is one syllable, whereas ***totally*** is ***three*** syllables. It's not as subtle as [the McGurk Effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UzWeZZ9XeQ) - where you hear what you *expect* to hear (***far*** or ***bar*** depending on whether you see the speaker's upper teeth). But it's in that general territory.

---

EDIT: I was distracted by people claiming the actress says ***totally***. She's actually saying ***totes*** (as in [*“I **totes** knew he liked you!”*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i%20totes%20knew%22&biw=1536&bih=747&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2000%2Ccd_max%3A2099%2Cbkv%3Ap&tbm=bks&ei=dmWuZL7rG8aXhbIPzrWhqAI&ved=0ahUKEwi-_sqd4YiAAxXGS0EAHc5aCCU4ChDh1QMICQ&uact=5&oq=%22i%20totes%20knew%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQkQhY3xBgqBVoAHAAeACAAaYBiAGzBJIBAzQuMpgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books))<sup>2</sup>, but the second /t/ is *deliberately* underarticulated to blur the distinction between ***Um... I totes speak*** and ***Er... My toes speak***. It's still an auditory pun, partly "licensed" by existing idiomatic uses of ***fingers and toes***.

---

<sup>2</sup> Appending extraneous ***/s/**'s* to informal slangy usages is a relatively new emerging trend, typified by ***[for reals](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22for%20reals%20she%22&biw=1536&bih=747&tbs=bkv%3Ap%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2000%2Ccd_max%3A2099&tbm=bks&ei=I4OuZOObH4iP8gKVrI04&ved=0ahUKEwijuZLE_YiAAxWIh1wKHRVWAwcQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22for%20reals%20she%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ6AdYqQ9g2hNoAHAAeACAAUKIAa0CkgEBNZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books), [funsies](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22funsies%22&biw=1536&bih=747&tbs=bkv%3Ap%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2000%2Ccd_max%3A2099&tbm=bks&ei=NIOuZPqcIq-khbIP9-Cc2A0&ved=0ahUKEwj6hqPM_YiAAxUvUkEAHXcwB9sQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22funsies%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQjgtYwCxghjRoAHAAeACAAWSIAaoLkgEEMTcuMpgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books), [hugsies](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hugsies%22&biw=1536&bih=747&tbs=bkv%3Ap%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2000%2Ccd_max%3A2099&tbm=bks&ei=Y4OuZJ2IFIWP8gKjw7-QDw&ved=0ahUKEwjdxcni_YiAAxWFh1wKHaPhD_IQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22hugsies%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAM6BQgAEIAEUNoLWMQbYPQfaABwAHgAgAFkiAHWBJIBAzguMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books)*** instead of ***for real*** (truly, totally), ***fun, hugs***.

Comment: Is some misguided anonymous downvoter *still* under the impression that the woman says ***I totally***? It's as clear as day that she says ***My toes***

Comment: No, she definitely does not say "my toes speak English." She says "Um, I totally speak English" and the second "t" of "totally" is slightly swallowed/a very very soft "d."

Comment: Wow! I'm boggled. We'll just have to agree to differ, unless we can get someone from the scriptwriters team to explain what they put in there, and why. But quite apart from your ideas about a "swallowed" /t/ (irrelevant, since there's a /t/ in both renditions), what do you think happened to the second and third syllables of ***totally***? They just seem to have vanished!

Comment: Perhaps it's your British ear leading you astray.

Comment: I grant the actress is carefully / deliberately blurring the distinction between ***umm... I*** and ***My***. But how can you explain three-syllable ***totally*** ending up as just one syllable ***toe*** (where again, the pluralising ***s*** is carefully and deliberately slurred into the first letter of ***s**peak*).

Comment: You can hear the ly. Here's me saying it the same way she does: https://voca.ro/17M679Mfh3dN

Comment: Also, another factual issue in your answer: the character Sunshine is an exchange student from the Philippines, and the actor who portrays her is also from the Philippines, not a native Anglophone.

Comment: @Katy in your audio I can hear easily the totally unlike in the link I sent...

Comment: @Katy: Do you have any *evidence* that the actress playing Sunshine is from the Philippines? Someone posting [an episode synopsis on IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1628278/plotsummary/?ref_=tt_stry_pl#synopsis) obviously had a brain fart - they've attributed the female character to a male actor called Jake Zyrus.

Comment: Jake Zyrus nee Charice is the actor who played Sunshine. And wow, did you really not bother to click through to his profile and check? “ Jake Zyrus (known as Charice Pempengco prior to his gender transition) was born in Cabuyao, Philippines.”

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkYtLDxZ27I  Here's an interview given at the time.

Comment: @Katy: I do have better things to do with my time than check to see whether some *currently* masculine actor's name leads to someone who's had a sex change (but not a corresponding *name* change). I also had better things to do than waste over three minutes listening to the entirety of the link you've posted, only to realize s/he isn't gonna even *mention* the line under the microscope here. Nothing that you've said so far gives me any reason to doubt my position - which I think I *have* promoted by finding ***My little toe knows more English than you!*** in text published some years ago.

Comment: If you have better things to do that be accurate—and you seem to have plenty of time to link to IMDb and cast aspersions on information that is actually correct—you should probably reconsider posting here. You asked for evidence that the actor was from the Philippines, and the interview link that I provided you contains that evidence.

Comment: @Katy: Please lose the hostile overtones. I thank you for providing evidence that Jake Zyrus is Phillipino. It doesn't affect the validity of my position here - but I did ask, and you responded. But did you not realize that nothing in the *interview* you linked to relates to the actual issue here? What was I supposed to make of that?

Comment: It's Filipino, not Phillipino. The interview relates to your request for evidence of the actor's national origin.

Comment: Jesus! Give it a rest, willya?

Comment: Putting aside the issue of the actor, "My little toe knows more English than you!" is a fine phrase, but it's a singular cite to a memoir about a woman's experience with her bilingual (English and Arabic-speaking) mother, and one of her mother's favorite phrases. It's not common enough to be an intentional pun on the part of the writers, and Glee relied on shock humor to a much greater degree than it engaged in wordplay.